# Is $\Delta u=\sum_{i=1}^n u_{x_i x_i}=-\Delta u$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Is $\Delta u=\sum_{i=1}^n u_{x_i x_i}=-\Delta u$?

Because this is what my lecture notes read.

Surely negating a sum of derivatives should be quantities of the opposite sign? So the equalities would not hold.

Why not?

Comment: Why are you writing $\sum_{i=1}^n u_{x_i x_i}=-\Delta u$?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is Laplacian sometimes defined as $-\operatorname{div}(\nabla f)$ and sometimes as $\operatorname{div}(\nabla f)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2511757/why-is-laplacian-sometimes-defined-as-operatornamediv-nabla-f-and-someti)

Answer (score 1):

No, obviously not, unless $\Delta u=0$, i.e. $u$ is harmonic.

Comment: Okay so the equality applies for solutions $u$ of Laplace equation and Poisson equation?